# Как скачать файл xlsm с сервера с помощью php?

Tags: php, excel

Нужно скачать с сайта файл в формате xlsm. Он лежит на сервере и если его перекинуть через ftp на компьютер, то все хорошо. А если скачивать с сайто, он не открывается, выходит ошибка "Формат или расширение файла являются недопустимыми". Скачиваю так же файл xls, он открывается, но русские символы отображаются в виде закорючек.

```
 header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel;charset:utf-8");
 header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . $fileName);
 echo file_get_contents('uploads/results/'.$toReturn->result);
```

Может, кто знает, что можно сделать?

Comment: Это `;charset:utf-8` удалите из заголовка.

Comment: Ничего не изменилось.

Answer (score 1):

Проверка наличия файла через file_exists() и его отдача через readfile() + правильный Content-Type для .xlsm и исправление ошибки в Content-Disposition:

```
$file = 'uploads/results/' . $toReturn->result;
if (! file_exists($file)) {
    exit('Нет файла или он лежит в другом месте :Р');
} else {
#    // для .xlsm 
#    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12');
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$fileName.'"');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
    exit; 
}
```

Comment: Ошибок нет, файл на месте, скачивание не идет.

Comment: @ЕвгенияМокко, изменил ответ на вариант стандартно предлагаемый мануалом http://php.net/manual/ru/function.readfile.php

Answer (score -1):

Почему просто не использовать функцию `copy(url, path_save)`?

Comment: помимо этого нужно ещё передать правильные заголовки

Comment: @LexHobbit является ответом. [Содержательный ответ удалён как «В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса»](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5703)

Comment: @Dmitry, это не ответ, так как функция copy() не может скопировать файл на компьютер пользователя.

Comment: @Visman это плохой ответ, так как он не решит проблему, обозначенную в вопросе, но тем не менее, это ответ. И наша задача -
 указать, что этот ответ плохой, отдав за него голос "против"

Comment: @Dmitry, я вангую, что постепенно, по мере пробегания по вопросам/ответам народа за медальками, этот ответ будет набирать плюсы, а не минусы.